# Getting attribute of a appended class

Tags: jquery

Using following function I am deleting a row which is kind of following format.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <select name="search_field_option[]" id="selectCount_3" class="form-control" onchange="removeSelected(this, 'ref_no')">
        <option value="ref_no">Refer ID</option>
        <option value="email">Email ID</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="address">Address</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I am using jquery append to generate row.
and when removing it I am using following function to remove it.

```
function removeRow(removeNum) {
    $('#rowCount' + removeNum).remove();
}
```

before removing it if I want to catch the selected option in that row how can I acieve that? for example If i remove the row where selected option is email, how can I catch it?

Comment: Where is the html element with the id `rowCount`, which you are using in the jQuery selector.

Comment: @Alvi_1987 what is 'ref_no' .?

Comment: You've also quoted a `removeRow` function, but HTML that refers to a `removeSelected` function in an `onchange` which clearly has not just a different name, but a different signature. Is that `removeSelected` related at all to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the select drop down trigger the function `getSelected()` and pass the `this` node then find the children with jQuery `is(':selected')` attribute. Then you can use `.val()` or `.text()` to get the value of displayed text respectively and use it

```js
function getSelected(node,x) {
  var selected = ($(node).find(':selected').val());
  alert(selected);
  //call your remove here
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <select name="search_field_option[]" id="selectCount_3" class="form-control" onchange="getSelected(this, 'ref_no')">
        <option value="ref_no">Refer ID</option>
        <option value="email">Email ID</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="address">Address</option></select>
</div>
```

Try this. after this call you can call remove of row or your logic

Comment: Code dumps are not very useful. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Comment: It's also not at all clear to me that the `onchange` handler is what's removing the row (the question is quite unclear).

Answer (score 0):

> before removing it if I want to catch the selected option in that row how can I acieve that?

Well, provided that `$('#rowCount'+removeNum)` really matches the structure in question (there's no element and an `id` like `rowCountNNN` in your quoted markup), then you'd use `find` to find the `select` within it, and `val` to get the `select`'s value:

```
function removeRow(removeNum) {
    var row = $('#rowCount'+removeNum);
    var val = row.find("select").val();
    row.remove();
    // ...use val...
}
```